# Is it possible to convert exe files to flv?

Tags: flash, converters, exe, flv

I have been given a number of file in exe format.

Once I click on the files they open in a browser.

The sections heading on the left can be clicked to play any section of the content.

Is it possible to have the same functionality but as an flv file? If so how can I do it?

I tried many softwares - all were a waste of time.

Comment: I am not sure what you are after. FLV files are video files, there is no interactivity with that. If you are asking if you can redo the system using Flash, yes you can. Can you break up the .exe files and turn them into Flash files (fla), I don't think so. All I have seen so far is convert swf to fla

Comment: Actually I was trying to do something impossible. However, I have realized the content can be downloaded as MP4 rather than EXE which means now conversion to FLV is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeking a way to extract an swf from a windows Flash Projector executable there is a tool by Northcode I used way back. It's called exe2swf and can be downloaded from this support page:

http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/08/02/Extract-SWF-files-from-Flash-Executables

Once you have your swf file there are several reverse engineering options to get back to a fla but only consider doing all this if this is your intellectual property and the original files were simply lost. One tool we used sucessfully on a complex project with just that situation is Sothink SWF Decompiler.